# How to obtain ag-grid changes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm trying to use ag-grid in an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm not using any framework in the client side.
The question is how to get the changes made in the grid to save the data in the database? As simple JavaScript array data?

I need something that return me the changed data like this:

```
added[1],     => {code:"", name: "newName"}
changed[1],   => {code:"01", name: "changedName"}
deleted[1]    => {code:"02", name: "toBeDeleted"}
```

Then, sending that to the server is easy, but once the server returns OK, how do I clean the changes flags?

Comment: This is not related to c#, ag-grid is developed on/with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rowValueChanged` or `cellValueChanged` for that. 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#editing

update data and use arrays to store references to updated, deleted or changed rows. On clicking save button anywhere in your app, you can get the rows and update in database.